# What is benefit of using java based config instead of web.xml for servlet 3.x

Tags: java, web.xml, servlet-3.0

With Servlet 3.x API, we can eliminate web.xml completely and migrate to Java Config. I always find web.xml as a very good debugging point to start understanding a web application. I fail to understand why we are planning to migrate to Java based config and remove web.xml completely. I have tried searching for an appropriate answer on internet but cannot find satisfactory explaination. Anyone can help me understand this in a practical scenario.

Comment: Compile time checking. If you need to upgrade to a newer version of a library and the package name has changed, you may push to production and not see that a lazily loaded servlet is failing. This can happen with Restlet for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It avoids repeating yourself, and making mistakes by doing so. The servlet class is, for example, `com.foo.bar.SomeServlet`. Using `web.xml`, you're forced to re-enter this class in web.xml:

```
<servlet-class>com.foo.bar.Someservlet</servlet-class>
```

But wait, you've made a typo and you'll only discover it at runtime.

Or you rename a servlet class, but you forget to rename it in the web.xml as well, and you only discover the mistake at deployment time.

Finally, they make our life easier. You're creating a servlet, and you obviously want to map it to some URL. So you just add an annotation. No need to go to another file to add the mapping, then go back to the class because you forgot its exact name, then go back to the file again. Everything regarding a servlet is in the servlet class. Same for a filter, listener, etc.

Annotations don't have all these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Descriptor-less deployment is an alternative to configuration files, but it's not intended to always replace the web.xml in every application and for every use case. If you need to be able to change the configuration without recompiling, then you should stick to deployment descriptor of course. Sometimes a centralized place where everything is setup can be easier to start. But it can also be less flexible because you need to set up everything explicitly and by hand.

One advantage of auto discoverable annotations is that they decouples your endpoints and make them independent. If you build a JAX-RS webservice for example, the web application only needs to provide the application path. It doesn't need to know which resources are actually available. It doesn't matter how the resource classes are named or in which package they are. The container will handle everything. Since it's all according to the servlet standard, you can just throw a war archive only with annotated servlets or resource endpoints in a servlet container and have them running. Or make it a wab archive and deploy the same thing as osgi web bundle. Add some DI and all this allows for highly modular web applications and easy use of independent micro services.

Actually you can get most of those benefits with web fragment descriptors too. On the other hand when you have dozens of `web-fragment.xml` files scattered all over the system, you'll loose the advantage of a clear application entry point too. At this point it probably depends on your preferences whether you use files or annotations.